# Searching through a flatlist returns no results

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, searchbar

I'm trying to get store names from a nested array but I'm getting no results, everything works fine but when I type in the search bar and I get nothing (Image below). I can see the flatlist again once I delete what I typed in.
I think the problem is with the data I'm returning from the filter.
Here's what I did so far.

```
const Purchases = () => {
    const extractKey = ({purchases}) => purchases.toString();
    const [search, setSearch] = useState(content);

    function _searchFilterFunction(searchText, data) {
        let newData = [];
        if (searchText) {
            newData = content.filter(function (item) {
                item.purchases.filter(function (i) {
                    const itemData = i.name.toUpperCase();
                    const textData = searchText.toUpperCase();
                    return itemData.includes(textData);
                })

            });
            setSearch([...newData]);
        } else {
            setSearch([...data]);
        }
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>

            <TextInput
                style={styles.textInputStyle}
                placeholder="Search by Store"
                onChangeText={(value) => {
                    _searchFilterFunction(value, content);
                }}
            />
         
            <FlatList
                data={search}
                renderItem={renderItem}
                keyExtractor={extractKey}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

and here's the array:

```
let content = [
    {
        date: 'September 8, 2012',
        total: 754,
        purchases: [
            {
                name: 'Virgin Megastores',
                time: '12:24',
                price: 432,
                icon: vms
            },
            {
                name: 'Apple Store',
                time: '13:43',
                price: 322,
                icon: apple
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        date: 'September 8, 2012',
        total: 754,
        purchases: [
            {
                name: 'Virgin Megastores',
                time: '12:24',
                price: 432,
                icon: vms
            },
            {
                name: 'Apple Store',
                time: '13:43',
                price: 322,
                icon: apple
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem lies with the way you filter your data.

```
newData = content.filter(function (item) {
    item.purchases.filter(function (i) {
        const itemData = i.name.toUpperCase();
        const textData = searchText.toUpperCase();
        return itemData.includes(textData);
    });
});
```

The `filter` function expects a callback function that returns a boolean to determine whether an item should be included or not. Because your `contect.filter` call doesn't return anything from its callback the final `newData` is empty.

So let's try to adjust the code into something working

```
newData = content.filter(function (item) {
    // check if any purchase has matches; and keep the filtered results
    const filteredPurchases = item.purchases.filter(function (i) {
        const itemData = i.name.toUpperCase();
        const textData = searchText.toUpperCase();
        return itemData.includes(textData);
    });

    // now let the parent know if it should include this item in the filter
    // if the length is higher than zero, filter will include this item
    return filteredPurchases.length;
});
```

In your comment you say that you only want to show the applicable purchases. Let's adjust the code a little bit more. We will `map` the content to only include applicable purchases and then `filter` on all items with applicable purchases

```
newData = content.map(function (item) {
    // check if any purchase has matches; and keep the filtered results
    const filteredPurchases = item.purchases.filter(function (i) {
        const itemData = i.name.toUpperCase();
        const textData = searchText.toUpperCase();
        return itemData.includes(textData);
    });

    // now return a newly composed item with only applicable purchases
    return {
      ...item,
      purchases: filteredPurchases
    };
}).filter(function (item) {
   // now only keep items with applicable purchases.
   return item.purchases.length
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but another problem came up now, each purchase inside the content array has two purchases as you can see, so when searching I'm getting the correct result in addition to the other one because an array is what it's returning. How can I get each purchase alone?

Comment: I extended the answer a bit more with some extra logic for you.